# Working with unordered list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I am trying to create sliding effect on this ul li structure.

```
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
<li class="liclass">This is a paragraph1.</li>
</ul>
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
<li class="liclass">This is a paragraph2.</li>
</ul>
```

and the jquery code I have used on this is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("ul").click(function (evt) {      
    if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL') 
        return;
    $("li", this).toggle();
});
```

});

But when I click on a ul element it shows sliding effect.But clicking on other ul I want to hide other shown li.

I have tried with

`$("li").not(this).toggle();`

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your solution is:

```js
$("ul").click(function (evt) {      
    
    $('li').slideUp();
    $(this).find('li').slideDown();
    
});
```

```css
.liclass{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
<li class="liclass">This is a paragraph1.</li>
</ul>
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
<li class="liclass" >This is a paragraph2.</li>
</ul>
```